# Flush MyBatis Cache externally (outside of mapper)

Tags: caching, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm using MyBatis with second level cache activated via `<cache/>` in xml mapper files.

Suppose I want to interact with the underlying DB/DataSource decoupled from MyBatis, for instance via direct jdbcTemplate.

How can I assure, that the MyBatis cache gets flushed appropriateley when I Insert/Update/Delete via jdbcTemplate on a table for that MyBatis holds cached query results.

In other words, how can I force MyBatis to flush its cache from outside of MyBatis mappers for certain cache namespace?

I'm aware of `@Options(flushCache=true)` annotation, but this seems not to work outside of mapper interfaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can get cache from configuration and then get by namespace and clear it.

```
    @Resource
    SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    public void clearCacheByNamespace(){
        Configuration config = sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration();
        Cache cache = config.getCache("com.persia.dao.UserInfoMapper");
        if(cache != null){
            cache.clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: not helpful, the question was outside of mybatis mapper

Comment: I update the answer , you can do it by getting cache from configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have used another approach, because we used spring. Use autowire the Session implementation and call appropriate method

```
public class SomeServerClass{

    @Autowired
    private org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate;

    private void someClearMethod(){
        sqlSessionTemplate.clearCache();
    }
}
```

If I use interface org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession it refers to same instance

Comment: As the JavaDoc of SqlSessionTemplate.clearCache() states "Clears local session cache" I assume this clears the local (per thread) cache rather than the global session-independent cache