# Why gets Mybatis TransactionalCache not cleared on cache.clear()

Tags: caching, mybatis, spring-transactions

Referencing the [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769226/flush-mybatis-cache-externally-outside-of-mapper) how to clear mybatis cache manually by code I stumbled over a issue with [TransactionalCache](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/reference/org/apache/ibatis/cache/decorators/TransactionalCache.html) which is the only MyBatis cache type which gets NOT cleared by calling `clear()` on every cache provided by `sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().getCaches`

In particular the member variables of `org.apache.ibatis.cache.decorators.TransactionalCache`

```
  private Map<Object, Object> entriesToAddOnCommit;
  private Set<Object> entriesMissedInCache;
```

are holding keys and values which should be chached on commit and which are not cached yet. So far so good.
In my optinion both should be cleared on `cache.clear()`, but the responsible `clear` method gets never invoked

```
 @Override
  public void clear() {
    clearOnCommit = true;
    entriesToAddOnCommit.clear();
  }
```

Is this a bug or are there any explanation or suggestion how to flush TransactionalCache?

Comment: BTW, clear meothods of every other dacorated cache like SerializedCache or LruCache gets invoked

Comment: Erm, is it really a good idea to be able to clear a Cache manually that seems to be wired heavily into the whole transaction system? To me it seems that the Cache is intended to react only to commit and flush events (via the TransactionalCacheManager).

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz unfortunately it is necessary since there are writing sql statements apart of mybatis (but within the same transaction/connection) which should flush the cache as well when they are invoked. Imho even the TransactionalCacheManager should clear its cache, otherwise entriesToAddOnCommit holds values which gets written to cache on commit which are not valid anymore. FYI my local cache scope is set to STATEMENT and not SESSION.